# C++ How to call a constructor parameter inside a class method

Tags: c++, oop

So I'm a total noob at C++, I decided to learn C++ and skipped directly to the Object-oriented programming. I'm coding a class called `KineticEnergy` that has a constructor with the parameters `x` and `y` which is assigned to the variables `mass` and `velocity`.

I have a class method called `result()` which calculates the Kinetic Energy using its formula. I want to call the parameters from my constructor within the formula but I have no idea what I'm exactly doing here (bad english, don't know how to explain). I am getting errors like "[Error] `x` was not declared in this scope". Here is the code I written:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

class KineticEnergy
{
    public:
        double mass;
        double velocity;
        
        KineticEnergy(double x, double y) {
            mass = x;
            velocity = y;
        }
        
        double result()
        {
            return (1/2) * (x * (pow(y, 2)));
        } // What am I gonna do here for this to work?
};

int main()
{
    double a = 12.1;
    double b = 6.4;
    
    KineticEnergy ke(a, b);
    cout << ke.result();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should use data members instead, which have been assigned from constructor's parameters. i.e. `return (1/2) * (mass * (pow(velocity, 2)));`

Comment: Note that `(1/2)` does an integer division and will result in `0`, not `0.5`.

Comment: A fellow C++ learner. Welcome! As far as I understand C++ code: When using parameters in your constructor (or any other method) the names of the parameters are basically just interface handles that take the parameters from the call of the method or constructor (so values that you defined in that scope where you call that method or constructor) and put them in the local scope of the method. So ```x``` and ```y```vanish as soon as you exit the scope of the constructor. But you have done the right thing and stored the values inside ```x ``` and ```y``` into your class member variables.

Answer (score 4):

It is not necessary. your constructor parameters is saved in "mass" and "velocity" as class members.

```
double result()
        {
            return (1./2.) * (mass * (pow(velocity , 2.)));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Parameters of the parameterized constructor are not member variables. That's why you are storing param values in member variables inside of the parameterized constructor. So that, you should use member variables inside of the result() function.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

class KineticEnergy
{
    public:
        double mass;
        double velocity;
        
        KineticEnergy(double x, double y) {
            mass = x;
            velocity = y;
        }
        
        double result()
        {
            return 0.5 * (mass * pow(velocity, 2));
        } 
};

int main()
{
    double a = 12.1;
    double b = 6.4;
    double Result;
    
    KineticEnergy ke(a, b);
    
    Result = ke.result();
    cout << Result;
}
```

x and y were declared in your constructor, therefore only known by your constructor. you cannot use them outside of it. however, mass and velocity are known variables of your class and can be used anywhere as long as they are public.

in your main you give mass and velocity of your `ke` object values, that's why you can call any method of your class that uses these variables after(again, as long as they're public)